# Twitter Bootstrap carousel restart after last slide showed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I made a website in Twitter Bootstrap and there is used Twitter Bootstrap carousel all is well but in carousel i have problem, when auto play start the carousel slide all images but when reached last slide it stopped there.
I want to make the slide like this but I have not find the code.
In this example it not stopped.
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

Answer (score 0):

HTML code for the Carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>   
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item"><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide 1"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Slide 3"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

Check out this page for working example - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-carousel.php